# flutter local notification with work manager ( navigation problem)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using work manager for background tasks and create local notification. I want to set my notifications like this: When I tap the notification, app open the specific page. But my code working before main dart so I can't use context. How can I use navigator local navigation with work manager.

I tried so many way to set that navigation but I couldn't find it.

this is my callbackDispatcher code before MyApp:

```
void callbackDispatcher( ) async{
 Workmanager().executeTask((dynamic task, dynamic inputData) async {
    print('Background Services are Working!');

................. some code in here .....................

        if(  count > await data()['count']) {


          FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flip = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
          var android = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
          var IOS = const IOSInitializationSettings();
          var settings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: IOS);
          flip.initialize(settings,);
          _showNotificationWithDefaultSound(flip);

................................................................

          FirebaseFirestore.instance.
          collection('counts').
          doc(uid).
          update({
            "count": counter++,

          }).
          catchError((e) {
            print(e);
          });
          return Future.value(true);} else{
          return true;
        }

      }
      return true;
    } on PlatformException catch (e, s) {
      print(e);
      print(s);
      return true;
    }
  }
  );
}
```

this is my _showNotificationWithDefaultSound code:

```
    Future _showNotificationWithDefaultSound(flip) async {

  // Show a notification after every 15 minute with the first
  // appearance happening a minute after invoking the method
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',

      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high
  );
  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const IOSNotificationDetails();

  // initialise channel platform for both Android and iOS device.
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics
  );
  await flip.show(
      0,
      'end of the calls',
      'you should click',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'unknown',
  );
}
```

and this is MyApp code:

```
    Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());

}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState()  {
    workmanagerFunction();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> workmanagerFunction () async{
    await Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: false);
    await  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
        'task',
        frequency:  const Duration(milliseconds: 1*60),
    existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.replace,

    );}
  
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Dentapros Call Logs',
      theme: ThemeData(
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.indigo.shade900)),

      home:   FirstPage(),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase_messaging plugin
for handling background push messages,

take help from this example
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp();`

from [flutter_foreground_task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task) package It's work so well for me.